# How is the received number of trophies calculated?

Tags: clash-of-clans

So I have been playing Clash of Clans for a while now and have noticed that the number of trophies received on a win greatly fluctuate. By this, I do not mean for a full win only. I am talking about winning with 1 and 2 stars mostly.

Does anyone know if the percentage of destruction on the enemy village has anything to do with the amount of trophies you get on said 'win'? I have a feeling that it does since I have looked at the number I receive from a 2 star at 50% and 2 star at 95%, but like I said its a personal thought. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of trophies you earn is not directly relative to the percentage of destruction. It depends on how many stars you earn. ( Read the bold text below )

According to the [Clash of Clans wiki, "Raids" article](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids):

> **For each star that you earn, you receive one-third of the available Trophies.** This means that destroying your opponent's Town Hall gives
>   you an automatic victory. Also it is impossible to get more than one
>   star without destroying the Town Hall. Failure to get any stars means
>   a loss, causing you to lose Trophies.

So for example, let's assume available trophy for a battle is 30. If you destroy the Town Hall and 50% of your opponent's base you will receive 20 trophies, and if you keep destroying it until 90%, you still will get 20 trophies.